# Unused Variable in C for sockaddr_un

Tags: c, sockets

I've copied a code snippet from several sources but for some reason I get an unused variable error for the saun variable when I try to implement. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "gfserver.h"


#include <sys/mman.h>

#define SOCKET_ADDR "sock_addr"
#define MAX_REQ_BUF 523

/* Main ========================================================= */
int main() {


  int sockfd;
  size_t n;
    struct sockaddr_un saun;
    int len;

    if ((sockfd =  socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    saun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(saun.sun_path, SOCKET_ADDR);
    len = sizeof(saun.sun_family) + strlen(saun.sun_path);
    struct sockaddr* sockaddptr;
    sockaddptr = &saun;
    if(connect(sockfd, sockaddptr, len) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR connecting socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    char request_buffer[MAX_REQ_BUF] = {0};
    n = write(sockfd,request_buffer,MAX_REQ_BUF - 1);
    if (n < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR writing to socket: %d\n",errno);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node28.html
http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/netguide/dusockT.code_samples.html

The above code is in a file called webproxy.c. It is essentially a part of a server program which will check a local cache via IPC. In another file (simplecached), there is another socket. For some reason this similar code doesn't give the same error until I remove the socket code from webproxy.c, then the simplecached code shows a similar compile error (Unused Variable for the same type of situation). I hesitate to add too much code at the risk of sharing too much of a school assignment so I apologize for that.

Compile Error:

```
make all 
mv gfserver.o gfserver.tmpo 
mv gfserver_noasan.o gfserver_noasan.tmpo
rm -rf *.o webproxy simplecached webproxy_noasan simplecached_noasan
mv gfserver.tmpo gfserver.o
mv gfserver_noasan.tmpo gfserver_noasan.o
cc -c -o webproxy.o -Wall --std=gnu99 -g3 -Werror -fPIC -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer webproxy.c
webproxy.c: In function ‘main’:
webproxy.c:15:23: error: storage size of ‘saun’ isn’t known
    struct sockaddr_un saun;
                       ^~~~
webproxy.c:15:23: error: unused variable ‘saun’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [webproxy.o] Error 1
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'webproxy.o' failed
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

15:21:58 Build Failed. 4 errors, 0 warnings. (took 177ms)
```

Comment: What is the exact error, or is it a warning? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Do you still get it if you use `&saun` instead of `sockaddptr`?

Comment: Too much code is missing here! a) Post the full code b) Post the exact error/warning you get from the compiler

Comment: The code you've presented is somewhat non-idiomatic, but variable `saun` certainly is used in it.  We might be able to lend a little more insight if you present a [mcve], including compilable code that demonstrates the problem (maybe just one function) and the exact diagnostic emitted by the compiler for that code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've added more details. Unfortunately I can't add too much code here at the risk of sharing too much of a school assignment. Thanks again! @Chris, yes that's what I tried first.

Comment: @MichaelG, we don't need or want to see your whole program, nor your makefile.  But the easiest and best way for you to help us help you would be for you to provide an ***MCVE***, as I described in my previous comment.  The handy hyperlink there leads to a fuller explanation of what that is and how to create one.  As it stands, there is (still) not enough information in the question for us to render an answer, whereas there is other information that we probably *don't* need, and that therefore just clouds the issue.

Comment: Thanks John, I was really just looking to see if there was something obvious I was missing as I'm relatively new to c programming. I need to go back and experiment some more. I copied the entire code from the link into my program and still received the same error if that's meaningful. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MichaelG The code in the links doesn't look anything like what you've got above.  You need to give us a piece of code that we can cut and paste *as is* that reproduces your problem.  Start by taking the above code, put it in a `main` function by itself and add any necessary includes and defines for it to compile.  If it reproduces your problem then post that, if not then see what's different and get that resolved.

Comment: @MichaelG, do note that the exercise of preparing an MCVE can serve as a powerful debugging technique in and of itself, even if you never intend for anyone else to see the result.  That would be a fine form for "go[ing] back and experiment[ing] some more" to take, and then if you do not solve the problem for yourself, you'll have something that we can more easily address here.

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify and include an MCVE.

Comment: OK, updated into an isolated main() function. Thanks.

Comment: Also updated with compile errors.

Comment: I found the problem, I wasn't including <sys/un.h>. Thanks for your help, if you're ever in Charlotte, message me and I'll buy you lunch.

Comment: @MichaelG Always address warnings / errors from the top down.